# RStudio doesn't work

Tags: r, rstudio

Why RStudio doesn't work after successful installation. When I'm opening RStudio (the up to data version V98.501) I see only a white desktop, the menu fields are completely paralized:[image]

The only option is either Reload or Inspect.
How Can I fix this problem? It occurd when I was trying to switch from R 2.15 to R 3.0.2, getting Tools --> General Options-- > Choose R Version.
I tried to remove all and install again, it doesn't help at all.

Comment: It looks like there might be something wrong with your `R` install. Have you tried reinstalling it as well? Are there any error messages?

Comment: I tried many times uninstall, and again reinstall both RStudio and R. It doesn't help. I can work with R but not with RStudio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, you can force RStudio to bind to a specific version of R by pressing and holding **Ctrl** when starting RStudio.